# Rails 2 vs Rails 3: Why are route globs no longer split?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2, glob

In Rails 2, if I had the following route:

```
get 'show/:user_id(/*tags)' => 'show#tags', :as => 'show_tags'
```

I would expect this back from show/123/foo/bar:

```
params[ :tags ] # [ 'foo', 'bar' ]
```

Now, in Rails 3, it returns:

```
params[ :tags ] # 'foo/bar'
```

Any idea why they changed this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router in rails was completely rewritten for Rails 3.0. It's outlined pretty well in **[The Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#action-dispatch)** on the subject. I would just consider it one of the many BC breaking changes of a transition between major versions.

The fix is very straightforward - just a small change to your action.

```
tags = params[:tags].split(/\//).reject(&:empty?)
```

Comment: Thank you. Shame that I technically have to doubly specify globs in both the router and the action. Not very DRY, but thanks so much for the insight!

Comment: Any easy way to override how Rails currently does it to make it behave like before by default?

Comment: @JasonTFeatheringham not that I know of; I'm not an expert on the router internals though.